# typedef problem

Tags: c, types, char, typedef, character

hey people kindly tell me if the following declaration is correct?

if it is then kindly explain

```
typedef char HELLO[5];

HELLO name;
```

now what datatype is name? [as in a character,integer etc]

i came to know that name will be an array of strings but when i run the following programme i  get error

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef char HELLO[5];

void main()
{
    HELLO name;
    name="hey";
    printf("%s",name);
}
```

error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘HELLO’ from type ‘char *’

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with typedef.  Your type is an array of characters also known as a c style string or a null terminated string for your usage.

You need to use `strcpy` or even better `strncpy` to copy a string into a char array.
Otherwise you can use the type `char*` and you can get the address of your string literal stored and then you can print it.

> i came to know that name will be an array of strings but when i run the following programme

The correct term would be an array of characters or a buffer. An array of strings might be confused to be an array of array chars.

Comment: You don't want to use `strncpy`, it doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 2):

`name` is of type `char[5]` - an array of 5 chars.

Defining `name` this way

```
typedef char HELLO[5];

HELLO name;
```

is equivalent to the definition:

```
char name[5];
```

You can't assign a string literal to a char array in C, as in your example.
You have to copy the characters from the literal to the array. You can use `strncpy()` for that.

```
strncpy(name, "hey", 4); // strlen("hey") == 3. 4 passed to strncpy, as the last
                         // argument causes it to add a null character at the end
```